# Pick the array by property name from another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I have an array like that

[image]

I want to pick the array item by property name, I am using lodash for that:

```
const result = _.map(this.thing, _.property('groups')).filter(x => x !== undefined);
```

But I am getting array of arrays as result

[image]

What I need is just single selected property array.

[image]

Any idea how to achieve that?

Comment: Why do you want to get rid of proto?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
const arr = [ {'groups': ['item1','item2']},
              {'categories':['x','y']}
            ]
            


var ouptut= arr.find(item=> { 
  return item[Object.keys(item).find(key=>key === 'groups')]
})

console.log(ouptut)
```

Comment: Spoking about the second approach, is there anyway to get rid of `if (key==='groups'){ console.log( item[key] }` and just make the whole thing kinda oneliner that return the expected result?

Comment: modified the approach

Answer (score 0):

Try this>>>

```js
var a = [{"p1":[3,4]},{"p2":[6,7]}];
function getArr(arr,key){
  var res = [];
  for(var v of arr){
    if(v[key]!=undefined){
      res = v[key];break;
     }
  };
  return res;      
}
console.log(getArr(a,"p1"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const output 
   = (Array.from(arr, (obj) => obj['product'], 'product')
        .filter(x => typeof x !== 'undefined'))[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can use ES6/ES7, you can rely on Object.keys and Object.values to access to the key (that is the property name) and the value (the array you want to get):

```js
var arr = [
 { groups: [1, 2 ] },
 { category: [1, 2, 3 ] },
 { subCategory: [1, 2, 3, 4 ] }
];

function pickArray(propertyName) {
 var element = arr.find(el => Object.keys(el)[0] === propertyName)
 return element ? Object.values(element)[0] : null;
}

var res = pickArray('category');
console.log(res);
```